# error en sql . SQL Error [932] [42000]: ORA-00932: tipos de dato inconsistentes: se esperaba DATE se ha obtenido DATE ORACLE

Tags: php, sql, oracle

tengo un inconveniente que no entiendo estoy tratando de que en una consulta de una tabla me traiga los ultimos registros de 6 meses desde la fecha actual solo con el sql y me sale el siguiente error

**SQL Error [932] [42000]: ORA-00932: tipos de dato inconsistentes: se esperaba DATE se ha obtenido DATE**

y solo necesito que se ordene del ultimo registo para atras (6 meses)

```
 SELECT region,tck,id_solicitud,fecha_solicitud,tipo_solicitud,
clasificacion,cantidad , localidad,
codigo,descripcion,proveedor FROM SOLICITUD_REPUESTOS WHERE  
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fecha_solicitud, 'DD/MM/YY'), 'YYYYMMDD'))
BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fecha_solicitud,sysdate)) AND 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fecha_solicitud,sysdate -180)))
```

Comment: ¿Y los formatos de `TO_DATE` en el `BETWEEN`?

Answer (score 1):

ya esta solucionado tenia la opcion de usar el SYSDATE despues del between

`TO_DATE(FECHA_SOLICITUD, 'DD/MM/YY') BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-180) AND  SYSDATE`

sin necesidad de usar TODA LA CONVERSION